# Sources of mkinitcpio MODULES=, BINARIES= and HOOKS= entries

Tags: mkinitcpio

How do I find out what will be added the `cpio` `initrd` image generated by `mkinitcpio` given an entry in either:

- `MODULES=`
- `BINARIES=`
- `HOOKS=`

For example, what files are included when adding `BINARIES="btrfs"`?

Answer (score 2):

As the name suggests, this is a `cpio` archive. It has been gzipped. So

```
zcat file | cpio -vt
```

will give you the contents.

Comment: I don't want the contents of the whole `initrd`, just the contents of a particular `MODULES=` entry. Where do they reside?

Comment: @TomHale I believe it might differ a lot between distributions.

Comment: Where is it on your distribution(s)?